# Generalizations of maximum theorem in parameterized optimization

Tags: optimization, non-convex-optimization

I have a parameterized optimization problem

\begin{eqnarray}
\max_{x\in D(\theta)} f(x,\theta)
\end{eqnarray}
Here state space $\Theta=(0,1)$; constraint correspondence $D:\Theta\to (0,+\infty)$ is a non-empty, continuous, compact-valued correspondence; the objective function $f(x,\theta)$ is continuous on $(0,1)\times (0,+\infty)$.

Then by the standard Berge's maximum theorem, the solution correspondence
\begin{eqnarray}
x^*(\theta)=argmax_{x\in D(\theta)} f(x,\theta)
\end{eqnarray}
is u.h.c and the
value function
\begin{eqnarray}
f^*(\theta)=f(x^*(\theta),\theta)
\end{eqnarray}
is continuous in $\theta$.

My question is: the continuity of $f^*(\theta)$ on $(0,1)$ doesn't impose enough regularity around the boundary point $0$ and $1$. For example, near $0$, the value function could behave eratically like $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ near $0$. But in the scenario that I consider, such kind of value function is super unlikely to arise. Unfortunately, due to the mathematical formulation, I cannot extend the optimization problem continuously to include the boundary points.

So, is there a generalization of maximum theorem that impose more structure on the value function? I want the value function to have a limit as $\theta$ approaches the boundary points. Unfortunately again, to require the objective function to have certain (quasi)-concavity/supermodularity is again impossible in my scenario.

I have done my literature search. It looks like that there are several generalizations in the direction of weakening the condition, but so far I haven't seen many generalizations in the direction of enhancing the conclusion.